# Screen tearing oddity when one window is on top of another with Radeon

Tags: 11.04, radeon, ati

I have a mobility radeon 5850 running 11.04 and am running catalyst 11.10 drivers. I noticed that whenever I have two windows open, one of top of the other, scrolling results in minor screen tearing, usually around the border of the window on the bottom.

When I minimize or close the bottom the tearing goes away. I have tear free desktop enabled and tried looking for this specific issue but couldn't find anyone else with it. It happens in both Unity and Classic. Is there any fix for this?

Edit: the tearing doesn't occur in xfce, so i'm thinking it might be related to gnome or compiz

Comment: Is this a fresh installation? Did you had any previous drivers installed?

Comment: i recently fresh installed 11.04 about a month ago and I noticed that it happened from the very beginning even before catalsyt 11.10 with the default "additional drivers" option enabled as well.

Comment: How did you remove the old drivers?

Comment: i deactivated fglrx in the "additional drivers" window, rebooted, and installed using the file from amd's website and did a aticonfig --initial

Comment: @KevinQiu - in ccsm - opengl plugin can you toggle "sync to vblank" - does that make a difference?

Comment: I think ati has a driver version 11.11 try to update see if it works.

Comment: i was hoping that might help but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Enable `vsync to vblank` in the CCSM panel, open a terminal and run

```
sudo aticonfig --sync-video=on
```

Reboot your computer

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: sync to blank makes the whole desktop choppy unfortunately. i think i'll just stick with xubuntu for now.